# Solr could not get value for property on Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: solr, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to install Broadleaf Commerce Community Edition (6.1.3-GA) on macOS.

I have successfully installed Solr 8.6.0 locally and get this response at http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=STATUS

```
{  
"responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":47},
  "initFailures":{},
  "status":{
    "catalog":{
      "name":"catalog",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.320Z",
      "uptime":126010809,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "catalog_reindex":{
      "name":"catalog_reindex",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog_reindex",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog_reindex/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.988Z",
      "uptime":126010160,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/catalog_reindex/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "customers":{
      "name":"customers",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.209Z",
      "uptime":126010941,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "customers_reindex":{
      "name":"customers_reindex",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers_reindex",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers_reindex/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.935Z",
      "uptime":126010216,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/customers_reindex/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "fulfillment_orders":{
      "name":"fulfillment_orders",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.209Z",
      "uptime":126010942,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "fulfillment_orders_reindex":{
      "name":"fulfillment_orders_reindex",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders_reindex",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders_reindex/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:32.934Z",
      "uptime":126010220,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/fulfillment_orders_reindex/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "orders":{
      "name":"orders",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"managed-schema",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:33.091Z",
      "uptime":126010063,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}},
    "orders_reindex":{
      "name":"orders_reindex",
      "instanceDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders_reindex",
      "dataDir":"/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders_reindex/data/",
      "config":"solrconfig.xml",
      "schema":"schema.xml",
      "startTime":"2020-08-04T03:13:33.110Z",
      "uptime":126010045,
      "index":{
        "numDocs":0,
        "maxDoc":0,
        "deletedDocs":0,
        "indexHeapUsageBytes":0,
        "version":2,
        "segmentCount":0,
        "current":true,
        "hasDeletions":false,
        "directory":"org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory:MMapDirectory@/Users/gunther/Desktop/solr-8.6.0/server/solr/solrhome/cores/orders_reindex/data/index lockFactory=org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLockFactory@5fb1ae26",
        "segmentsFile":"segments_1",
        "segmentsFileSizeInBytes":69,
        "userData":{},
        "sizeInBytes":69,
        "size":"69 bytes"}}}}
```

As you can see Solr seems to be working but i get this error while compiling Broadleaf Commerce:

```
ERROR 47828 --- [           main] o.b.c.s.s.s.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl   : Could not get value for property[Product.productAttributes(heatRange).value] for product id[2]

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.invokeMethod(PropertyUtilsBean.java:2116) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getMappedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:690) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getMappedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:614) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:804) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464) ~[commons-beanutils-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrHelperServiceImpl.getPropertyValueInternal(SolrHelperServiceImpl.java:952) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrHelperServiceImpl.getPropertyValue(SolrHelperServiceImpl.java:430) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.SolrHelperServiceImpl.getPropertyValue(SolrHelperServiceImpl.java:424) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.getPropertyValues(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:677) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.attachIndexableDocumentFields(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:526) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.buildDocument(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:506) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.buildIncrementalIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:436) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl$1.buildPage(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:229) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.buildIncrementalIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:386) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl$2.execute(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:269) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.performCachedOperation(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:173) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.executeSolrIndexOperation(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:256) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.buildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:198) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.search.service.solr.index.SolrIndexServiceImpl.rebuildIndex(SolrIndexServiceImpl.java:185) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl.java:54) ~[boot-community-demo-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b84b8451.invoke(<generated>) ~[boot-community-demo-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:752) ~[spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:691) ~[spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at com.community.core.service.search.SolrIndexCleanupServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1576716f.rebuildIndexAtStartupIfNecessary(<generated>) ~[boot-community-demo-core-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:261) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:179) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:142) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:172) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:165) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:403) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:897) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553) ~[spring-context-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) ~[spring-boot-2.1.15.RELEASE.jar:2.1.15.RELEASE]
        at com.community.admin.AdminApplication.main(AdminApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A locale could not be found for the provided localeCode: en_DE
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.i18n.service.TranslationServiceImpl.shouldTranslateLocale(TranslationServiceImpl.java:236) ~[broadleaf-common-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.i18n.service.TranslationServiceImpl.getTranslatedValue(TranslationServiceImpl.java:189) ~[broadleaf-common-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.i18n.service.TranslationServiceImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f73424a7.invoke(<generated>) ~[broadleaf-common-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218) ~[spring-core-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:687) ~[spring-aop-5.1.16.RELEASE.jar:5.1.16.RELEASE]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.i18n.service.TranslationServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2ed43831.getTranslatedValue(<generated>) ~[broadleaf-common-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.common.i18n.service.DynamicTranslationProvider.getValue(DynamicTranslationProvider.java:48) ~[broadleaf-common-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductAttributeImpl.getName(ProductAttributeImpl.java:116) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        at org.broadleafcommerce.core.catalog.domain.ProductImpl.getProductAttributes(ProductImpl.java:921) ~[broadleaf-framework-6.1.3-GA.jar:na]
        ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Here is the relevant content from solr-8.6.0/server/logs

```
2020-08-05 17:18:43.914 INFO  (qtp2138005960-24) [   x:catalog_reindex] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [catalog_reindex]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={wt=javabin&version=2}{deleteByQuery=namespace:("d") (-1674206693462900736)} 0 3
2020-08-05 17:18:43.937 INFO  (qtp2138005960-21) [   x:catalog_reindex] o.a.s.u.p.LogUpdateProcessorFactory [catalog_reindex]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&softCommit=false&wt=javabin&version=2}{commit=} 0 2
```

I have read question 53358713, I do not think it is the same. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try entering `en_DE` into `BLC_LOCALE`

```
INSERT INTO BLC_LOCALE (LOCALE_CODE, DEFAULT_FLAG, FRIENDLY_NAME, CURRENCY_CODE) VALUES ('en_DE', FALSE, 'English (Germany)', 'EUR');
```

Comment: Thank you a lot! Phillip, I spent hours on this yesterday